# Does flask-login query the db for every protected page request?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-login

I'm setting up a Flask server wherein the users can register/login to visit some protected page. I'm using `flask-login` for user-session management.

I was able to successfully set-up the basic login server with MongoDB as the database.

```
# Importing all the necessary flask_login components
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user, current_user


# Necessary Flask-Login initialization like,
login_manager = LoginManager()     # init loginManger
login_manager.init_app(app)        # init the app
login_manager.login_view = "login" # set the default view


# The User Class that implements the User properties.

''' 
About the user properties:
A user can be of one of two types, let's call them Type A and Type B.
Every user has a username and an email-id.

Lets call these attributes as boolean: isTypeA & string: emailId & username
'''

# Beginning of the User class
class User():
    # from flask-pymongo
    dbInstance = mongo.db.organizations

    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id

        print ("Fetching the Db for the user")        
        '''
           Here I am making the actual DB query for fetching the user details. Then I populate the self.isTypeA, self.emailId and
           self.username.
        '''

        # end of init

    def is_authenticated(Self):
        return True

    # And other functions like is_active, get_id, etc.
# End of the User Class

# My load_user function.
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print ("loading user")
    return User(user_id)
```

## The Problem

Here are the server logs whenever I log in a user from the login page.

```
loading user
Fetching the Db for the user
```

This is the expected behavior as I execute the load_user() while logging the user into the db.

Once the user is validated I redirect them to the protected page (let's assume that the protected page is some static page with no db interactions necessary).

Here are the server logs when I refresh the protected page.

```
loading user
Fetching the Db for the user
```

Is this the expected behavior? Is the user is loaded every time a protected page is being accessed? The logs above state that the db is being queried every-time just for ensuring the user is logged in or not? Isn't this what the sessions or cookies do? Isn't the user.properties stored locally? Is there a better way of implementing this so that the db doesn't have to be queried every time someone refreshes the page.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll always need to query the db on every request, because the web is a stateless environment. Why exactly do you think this is a problem?

Comment: I see. There is a session key already stored on the client end, isn't that all that's necessary to validate a user? I thought it was a problem as all I am trying to do is display a static page, and db being queried on every request seemed costly. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: What if access is revoked or additional roles are added, and your session data is not refreshed on a request? It seems like a security risc to only trust temporarily saved session data (which might even be altered by a user during his session).

Comment: Good point, the db needs to fetched at least to ensure the data authenticity. Thanks for the comment.